# JBoss Maven BOMs and transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I'm trying to use a number of the BOMs in the org.jboss.bom group to bring in the API stacks that are compatible with EAP 6.3.0. My understanding is, that's what they're for. But when I reference them (using 'provided' or even 'compile' scope), the dependencies don't become transitively available. Given that "compile" scope is used on the items inside the BOMs, [Maven's documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) of the dependency mechanism seems to indicate that those items should be added to the classpath of my project. Yet I'm getting undefined symbols for the classes that should be brought in.

For example, in project P, I'm including org.jboss.bom.wfk:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-spring:2.4.0-redhat-2 with 'provided' scope, yet org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext is undefined in P.

This is all happening in JBoss Dev Studio 8.1.0.GA, if that makes a difference.

Comment: `using 'provided' scope` *does* make the difference here.

Comment: @Tome I don't think the difference made by "provided" explains what I'm seeing. But thank you for making me re-read the table in the Maven document, because I can now describe my problem more clearly. I somehow thought the table was giving me a specific outcome when the scope of a dependency in the BOM is unspecified. Editing the description accordingly...

Comment: m2e plugin versions are: m2e 1.5.1, m2e wtp 1.1.0, org.jboss.tools.maven.* 1.6.2-Final

Comment: If you specify a dependency without scope, its scope is `compile` (and in fact also runtime). If you specify a dependency as `provided`, its own deps are not transitively added. It might not be clear on the table in the Maven documentation, but it works like that.

Comment: @Tome See the original docs: `This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.` [maven dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: I meant setting `<provided>` to the BOM dependency will make all its deps `provided` too, so not present at runtime. I do agree that it does not seem to be the issue here though.

Comment: @Tome yes: unspecified -> compile. The first notion I got from that table was fancier, and very wrong. So what I'm currently seeing (and the description now reflects) is that the BOM is structured just fine to include the dependencies, but they're not getting included. The Dependency Hierarchy view in m2e's POM editor shows BOM nodes with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself by reading the Maven Dependency documentation in more detail.

Here's my take-away: you *cannot* depend on the Eclipse m2e plugin to see you through the Maven dependency weeds. Know when/how to use the `<dependencyManagement>` section of the POM (and when not to use it). Know in particular the specific invocation Maven needs when you want to use a BOM: import the BOM in a `<dependencyManagement>` section with `<type>` of `pom` and `<scope>` of `import`, and then in the "regular" `<dependencies>` section (*not* `<dependencyManagement>`) specifically call out the sub-artifacts you need from the POM, but *omit the version*. (It's all spelled out [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).)

The intent of the BOM is not to allow you to mass-import dependencies by referencing only the BOM artifact; rather, it's to make sure the versions of dependencies are the right ones, as defined by the BOM.

Do not assume that Maven allows you to express things in logically/mathematically reduced terms. Find out how to please the beast, and do not rely on a wizard to figure this out for you. Read the Maven docs in detail, find out the recipes and follow them exactly.